# what is the method for determining the answers for this simple trig equation?

Tags: trigonometry

how do you determine the answers for $\sin 2 \theta =0$ within the range $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant2\pi $ ?

The answers I get from looking at a table of $\sin \theta$ values are

$0$, $\pi$ and $2 \pi$

while the answers provided by a specimen paper from the examination body are

$0$, $\pi/2$, $\pi$, and $3\pi/2$

What is the correct way to determine the answers and are my answers wrong?

Comment: Your table values are for $\sin\theta$ but you want the values for $\sin 2\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look in the range $[0,4\pi]$ for values of $\sin(\theta)=0$ if you want the values of $\sin(2\theta)=0$ to be in the range $[0,2\pi]$.

This is essentially because if we found values in $[0,4\pi]$ which solve $$\sin(\theta)=0,$$ then since this is the same as $$\sin\left(2\cdot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)=0,$$

We can use the same values of $\theta$ found except divided by two, which now puts them in the range $[0,2\pi]$.

Just to make this more explicit, the solutions in $[0,4\pi]$ are $$0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi,4\pi,$$ and now divide these by two to give:
$$0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten that you are solving:
$$sin(2\theta)$$ not $$sin(\theta)$$
You have found that:
$$2\theta=0$$
$$2\theta=\pi$$
$$2\theta=2\pi$$
Therefore:
$$\theta=0$$
$$\theta=\pi/2$$
$$\theta=\pi$$
However, there are more answers in the range given. These are:
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}$$ and $$2\pi$$
The answer book has forgotten about $$2\pi$$
However, it is an answer because the range is less than or equal to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, might I ask how you got $3\pi/2$ and  $2\pi$? i understand the rest except for that part.

Comment: I also agree that either the answer book forgot $2\pi$, or the op/exam meant $0\leq \theta<2\pi$

Comment: If you think that sin(2*answer)=0 then you can see that $$\frac{3\pi}{2}*2 =3\pi$$ and $$3\pi$$ is an answer because $$sin(3\pi)=0$$ same for the other.